# a text-based Role-Playing Game with java

Tags: java, beginner, adventure-game

The `Character` class is the base class, which is the superclass of `Enemy` and `Hero`.

Here is part of `Character.java`, the rest of it are just auto generated setters and getters.

```
public class Character implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int maxHp, hp, attack, defense, level;
    private int place, xp, gold;
    private String name;

    public void setHp(int hp) {
        if (hp>maxHp){
            this.hp = maxHp;
        } else {
            if(hp<0){
                this.hp = 0;
            } else {
                this.hp = hp;
            }
        }
    }

    public Character(String name, int maxHp, int attack, int defense, int xp, int gold, int level) {
//        super(); // Is it necessary to call super() here?
        this.name = name;
        this.maxHp = maxHp;
        this.hp = maxHp;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.xp = xp;
        this.gold = gold;
        this.level = level;
    }

}
```

The `Hero` class does the jobs related to the hero/player.

```
public class Hero extends Character implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int numAtkUpgrades, numDefUpgrades, pots;

    public Hero(String name) {
        super(name, 1100, 300, 200, 0, 0,1);
        numAtkUpgrades = 0;
        numDefUpgrades = 0;
        pots = 0;
        setPlace(0); // 0: Palace; 1: Woods(Lv1/Goblin); 2: Mountain(Lv2/Ogre); 3: Dragon Valley
    }

    public int chooseTrait(){
        Util.printHeading("Choose a trait");
        String[] choices = {"Upgrade attack", "Upgrade defense"};
        int upTrait = Util.makeAChoice(choices);
        return upTrait;
    }

    public void heroInfo(){
        Util.clearConsole();
        Util.printHeading(getName() + "'s INFO");
        Util.pln("Level: " + getLevel());
        Util.pln("Golds: " + getGold());
        Util.pln("XP: " + getXp());
        Util.pln("HP: " + getHp() + "/" + getMaxHp());
        Util.pln("Attack: " + getAttack());
        Util.pln("Defense: " + getDefense());
        Util.pln("Potions: " + getPots());
        Util.pln("Place:" + getPlace());
        Util.printSeperator(20);
        Util.anythingToContinue();
    }

    public void upLevel(){
        if(shouldUpLevel()){
            Util.clearConsole();
            Util.pln("Congratulations! Level UP!");
            int upTrait = chooseTrait();
            setXp(getXp()-nextLevel());
            setLevel(getLevel()+1);
            setMaxHp(getMaxHp()+100);
            setHp(getMaxHp());
            if(upTrait==1){
                numAtkUpgrades++;
                setAttack(getAttack()+100);
                Util.printHeading(getName() + " chose Upgrade Dttack");
            }else if(upTrait==2){
                numAtkUpgrades++;
                setDefense(getDefense()+100);
                Util.printHeading(getName() + " chose Upgrade Defense");
            }
            heroInfo();
        }
    }

    public boolean shouldUpLevel(){
        if(getXp()>=nextLevel()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int nextLevel(){
        int ret = 0;
        int currentLevel = getLevel()+1;
        ret = (int)(5 * (Math.pow(currentLevel, 2)) - (5*currentLevel));
        return ret;
    }

    public int getNumAtkUpgrades() {
        return numAtkUpgrades;
    }

    public void setNumAtkUpgrades(int numAtkUpgrades) {
        this.numAtkUpgrades = numAtkUpgrades;
    }

    public int getNumDefUpgrades() {
        return numDefUpgrades;
    }

    public void setNumDefUpgrades(int numDefUpgrades) {
        this.numDefUpgrades = numDefUpgrades;
    }

    public int getPots() {
        return pots;
    }

    public void setPots(int pots) {
        this.pots = pots;
    }

    public static Hero getHero(){
        Hero player = Util.deserializeHero();
        if(Objects.isNull(player)){
            String name = "Sigurd";
            player = new Hero(name);
        }
        return player;
    }

    public static void clearDb(){
        File file = new File("gamedb");
        if(file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Enemy` class generates all kinds of enemies, where I just put one temporally and I will put mroe.

```
public class Enemy extends Character {
    public static String[] enemies = {"OgreTank", "OgreWarrior", "GoblinTank", "GoblinWarrior", "GoblinAssassin"};

    public Enemy(String name, int maxHp, int attack, int defense, int xp, int gold, int level) {

        super(name, maxHp, attack, defense, xp, gold, level);

    }

    public static Enemy goblinAssassin(){
        return new Enemy("GoblinAssassin", 500, 700, 50, 10, 5,1);
    }

    // todo: many other kinds of enemies, such as "OgreTank", "OgreWarrior" etc.

}
```

The class `Util` provides all kinds of utilities for interaction with the player. I put `clearDb()` in `Hero` rather than here to prevent the auto-proposals from the editor, as I use `Util.clearConsole()` a lot.

```
public class Util {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void printL(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void pln(Object str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static int readInt(String prompt, int userChoice){
        int input;
        do{
            System.out.println(prompt);
            try {
                input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                input = -1;
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer!");
            }

        }while (input<1||input>userChoice);
        return input;
    }

    public static int makeAChoice(String[] choices){
        if(choices.length>0){
            for(int i = 1;i<=choices.length;i++){
                pln("(" + i + ") " + choices[i-1]);
            }
            int input = Util.readInt("-> ", choices.length);
            return input;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void clearConsole(){
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if(osName.toLowerCase().contains("windows")){
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                System.out.println();
        }else {
            System.out.print("\33[2J\33[1;1H");
            System.out.println("\33[2J\33[1;1H");
        }
    }

    public static void printSeperator(int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            System.out.print("- ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printHeading(String title){
        printSeperator(30);
        System.out.println(title);
        printSeperator(30);
    }

    public static void anythingToContinue(){
        System.out.println("\n Enter anything to continue...");
        scanner.next();
    }

    public static boolean serializeHero(Hero player){

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
                    new FileOutputStream("gamedb");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                    out.writeObject(player);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static Hero deserializeHero() {

        File file = new File("gamedb");
        if(!file.exists()){
            return null;
        }
        Hero player = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn =
                    new FileInputStream("gamedb");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            player = (Hero)in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Hero class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return player;
    }

}
```

The class `GameLogic` implements the main logic of the game.

```
public class GameLogic {
    static Hero player;
    public static boolean isRunning;
    // acts: see checkAct() method
    public static int act=1;

    public static void startGame() throws Exception{
        player = Hero.getHero();
        Util.clearConsole();
        System.out.println("\t\t\t-- JavaMUD --");
        if(player.getPlace()==0){
            Story.printIntro();
            player.setPlace(1);
        }

        // uncomment the following block to enable the player set hero's name
//        boolean nameSet=false;
//        String name;
//        do {
//            Util.clearConsole();
//            Util.printHeading("Your name: ");
//            name = Util.scanner.next();
//            Util.clearConsole();
//            Util.printHeading("Your name is "+name+".\nIs that correct?");
//            System.out.println("(1) Yes!");
//            System.out.println("(2) No, I want to change my name!");
//            int input = Util.readInt("-> ", 2);
//            if (input == 1){
//                nameSet = true;
//                player.setName(name);
//            }
//        }while (!nameSet);

        isRunning = true;
        gameLoop();
    }

    public static void checkAct(){ //printMenu
        Util.clearConsole();
        System.out.println("Choose an action");
        String[] choices = {"Fight Here", "Move On", "Hero Info", "Shop & Merchant (Cost 15 Golds)", "Hotel & Hospital (Cost 5 Golds)", "Start Over"};
        int act = Util.makeAChoice(choices);
        if(act==1){
            randomBattle();
        } else if(act==2){
            // todo: places
            // 0: village
            // 1: lvl 1 enemies
            // 2: lvl 2 enemies
//            place++;
        } else if(act==3){
            player.heroInfo();
        } else if(act==4){
            // Shop & Merchant
            if(player.getGold()<15){
                Util.pln(player.getName() + " doesn't have enough golds");
            }else {
                player.setPots(player.getPots() + 1);
                player.setGold(player.getGold() - 15);
                Util.pln(player.getName() + " got 1 potion");
            }
        } else if(act==5){
            // hotel + hospital
            if(player.getGold()<5){
                Util.pln(player.getName() + " doesn't have enough golds");
            }else {
                player.setHp(player.getMaxHp());
                player.setGold(player.getGold() - 5);
                Util.pln(player.getName() + "got a rest");
            }
        }  else if(act==6){
            Util.pln("Do you really want the hero back to level 1 and 0 XP?");
            String[] opts = {"Yes", "No"};
            int opt = Util.makeAChoice(opts);
            if(opt==1){
                Hero.clearDb();
            }else {

            }
        } else {
            Util.pln("error");
        }
    }

    public static void randomBattle(){
        Util.clearConsole();
        Util.printHeading("You encountered an evil minded creature. You'll have to fight it!");
//        Util.anythingToContinue();
        // todo: generate the enemies at random
        battle(Enemy.goblinAssassin());
    }

    public static boolean isBattleFinished(Hero player, Enemy enemy, int dmgDealt, int dmgTook){

        if(dmgTook < 0)
            dmgTook=10;

        if(dmgDealt < 0)
            dmgDealt = 10;

        enemy.setHp(enemy.getHp()-dmgDealt);
        player.setHp(player.getHp()-dmgTook);

        Util.clearConsole();
        Util.printHeading("Battle");
        Util.pln("You dealt " + dmgDealt + " damage to the " + enemy.getName() + ".");
        Util.printSeperator(15);
        Util.pln("The " + enemy.getName() + " dealt " + dmgTook + " damage to you.");
        if(player.getHp() <= 0){
            playerDied();
            return true;
        }else if(enemy.getHp() <= 0){
            Util.printHeading(player.getName() + " defeated the " + enemy.getName() + "!");
            player.setXp(player.getXp() + enemy.getXp());
            player.setGold(player.getGold() + enemy.getGold());
            Util.pln(player.getName() + " got " + enemy.getXp() + " XP!");
            Util.printSeperator(15);
            Util.pln(player.getName() + " got " + enemy.getGold() + " Gold!");
            Util.anythingToContinue();
            if(player.shouldUpLevel()){
                player.upLevel();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void battle(Enemy enemy){
        while (true){
            Util.printHeading(enemy.getName() +
                    "\nHP: " + enemy.getHp() + "/" + enemy.getMaxHp());
            Util.printHeading(player.getName() + "\nHP: " + player.getHp() + "/" + player.getMaxHp());
            System.out.println("Choose an action");
            Util.printSeperator(20);
            String[] choices = {"Attack", "Defend", "Run Away", "Auto", "Potion"};
            int act = Util.makeAChoice(choices);
            int dmgDealt = 0;
            int dmgTook = 0;

            if(act == 1){
                dmgDealt = player.getAttack() - enemy.getDefense()/2;
                dmgTook = enemy.getAttack() - player.getDefense()/2;
            } else if(act == 2){
                dmgDealt = player.getAttack() - enemy.getDefense()/2;
                dmgTook = enemy.getAttack() - player.getDefense();
            } else if(act == 3){
                Util.pln("run away");
                // todo: run away
            } else if(act == 4){
                Util.pln("auto");
                // todo: auto
            } else if(act == 5){
                if(player.getPots()>0){
                    player.setPots(player.getPots()-1);
                    player.setHp(player.getMaxHp());
                    Util.pln(player.getName() + " drank a potion that restored health to " + player.getMaxHp());
                } else {
                    Util.pln(player.getName() + " doesn't have any potions");
                }
            } else {
                Util.pln("Exceptions");
            }

            boolean isFinished = isBattleFinished(player, enemy, dmgDealt, dmgTook);
            if (isFinished){
                Util.serializeHero(player);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playerDied(){
//        Util.clearConsole();
        Util.printHeading(player.getName() + " died...");
//        Util.printHeading("You earned " + player.getXp() + " XP on your journey. Try to earn more next time");
        Util.pln("Use Potion and Rest wisely next time!");
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public static void gameLoop(){
        while (isRunning) {
            checkAct();
        }
    }

}
```

The class `Story` is a little bit trivial.

```
public class Story {
    public static void printIntro(){
        Util.printSeperator(30);
        System.out.println("The dragon took the princess, the hero is going to save her!");
        Util.printSeperator(30);
        Util.anythingToContinue();
    }
}
```

The last one give the entry point of the program.

```
public class GameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        GameLogic.startGame();

    }
}
```

I'm inspired by a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiuAYTl0L-gHgqyWtUKAAhtrTymOLHd28) though I made a lot of modification and I'm working on more features.

Comment: I see way too many static methods.  Ideally, the only static method in your code should be the main method.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you. Would you please give a link to a post that explains why the only static method should be the main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comments

Comments should be reserved for extra information that's not contained in the code, really you're looking for 'why' you are doing something.  Unnecessary comments add noise to the code which can be distracting, hiding the important bits of your code.  More often than not, comments are trying to tell you that your code could be refactored to make it clearer.  For example:

```
// uncomment the following block to enable the player set hero's name
```

To me, this is suggesting one of three things.

- The code isn't needed, so should be deleted (presumably you'll have a copy in source control if you want to reinstate it in the future).
- The code needs to have a flag/constant so that you can set this behaviour at compile time.
- The code needs to have some kind of configuration so that the block can be enabled/disabled by configuration.

Another comment that seems to be talking is:

```
} else if(act==5){
    // hotel + hospital
```

The comment seems to be needed because it's not really obvious what `act==5` refers to.  One approach to make the code more self-documenting would be to define a constant or an enum for the possible choices, at which point the comment becomes redundant.

### clearConsole

As a user, I *hate* this.  For me, console games should scroll.  If I play the game and end up losing, I can scroll back up and see where I went wrong.  If I have a particularly good adventure, then I can scroll back, copy and paste it easily into something either to keep, or to share.  If you clear the console, these options go away.  Consider if it's really adding to / detracting from the game play experience.

### empty clauses

You don't need to add clauses that don't do anything, so you should never need to do this:

```
}else {

}
```

If you do feel like you *really* need them, then consider adding a comment to say why.

### Start Over

Start over doesn't really start over.  It deletes the file, however it doesn't reset the current hero instance.  Consequently, the level doesn't change and eventually when the player does something else, it is saved back into the file.

### pln

So, it's good that you've created some separation between your logic and your UI, it will be make it easier if you decide that you want to have a different UI in the future.  However `pln` is really not a descriptive name.  `print`, `println`, `sendToUser` may be better options.  You've also got another method that does exactly the same thing `printL`, which is never called, and takes a `String` instead of an `Object`.  Redundant code should be removed (it's just extra distracting noise).  Do you need your print to support classes other than `String`?  If not then it should probably take a `String` argument.

### System.out.println

You've created a console wrapper `pln`, however sometimes you're also using `System.out.println` directly.  This will make it harder if you decide to output to somewhere other than the console.  So rather than doing:

```
    printSeperator(30);
    System.out.println(title);
    printSeperator(30);
```

Consider:

```
    printSeperator(30);
    pln(title);
    printSeperator(30);
```

### MakeAChoice

One of the reasons that you're using `println` appears to be to add a title, just before you as the player to make a choice.  This repeated logic suggests that perhaps you need to be able to specify a title when making a choice.

### checkAct

If you have a lot of `if(x==1) else if (x==2) else if(x==3)` etc, then it's a good candidate for a `switch` statement, so you may want to consider using that in future.

Some of the selected actions are performed in the method itself, an others delegate to other methods to handle.  Generally I try to have functions that are operating on all inputs at the same level of abstraction, so either they all handle it in the method, or more likely they all delegate.  This makes the methods easier to read.  On possibility for simplifying this method would be to have it table driven, rather than number driven.  This helps to remove some of the distributed knowledge (selections have indexes and the indexes are returned).  So for example, a 'selection' class could be defined in util for use with a `selectAction` function:

```
static class Selection {

    private final String choice;
    private final Runnable action;

    private Selection(String choice, Runnable action) {
        this.choice = choice;
        this.action = action;
    }

    static Selection selection(String choice, Runnable action) {
        return new Selection(choice, action);
    }

    public String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }

    public Runnable getAction() {
        return action;
    }
}

public static Runnable selectAnAction(String title, List<Selection> selections) {
    sendToUser(title);

    if (selections.isEmpty()) {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Selections must be > 0");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= selections.size(); i++) {
        sendToUser("(" + i + ") " + selections.get(i - 1).choice);
    }
    int selected = Util.readInt("-> ", selections.size());

    return selections.get(selected - 1).action;
}
```

By using this, `checkAct` gets shortened to just defining the mapping between selection text and selection action:

```
public static void checkAct() { //printMenu
    var selections = asList(selection("Fight Here", GameLogic::randomBattle),
            selection("Move On", GameLogic::notImplemented),
            selection("Hero Info", player::heroInfo),
            selection("Shop & Merchant (Cost 15 Golds)", GameLogic::visitShop),
            selection("Hotel & Hospital (Cost 5 Golds)", GameLogic::rest),
            selection("Start Over", GameLogic::startOver));
    var action = Util.selectAnAction("Choose an action", selections);
    action.run();
}
```

Notice that this assumes the logic for each of the act clauses has been extracted into it's own function (visitShop, rest, startOver, notImplemented).